# Is font-family: arial something that will work on every computer and mobile device?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have spent a long time reading about the advantages of using "open sans", "promima nova", "Helvetica Neue" and some other new fonts which I am told are all better than those fonts we have been using for a long time.

But when it comes down to it. Will most people actually notice any difference and what if I just use Arial in my font-family with no backup font at all.

If my users are using the modern browsers / modern operating systems from the last couple of years will that be a good choice for a very readable font or is there another font stack that people can recommend?

One recommendation I saw was to use the stack:

```
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
```

But why?  Is not Arial installed on every computer?

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With services like [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) and others like it (no affiliation), this question becomes less important. Such font services allow you to choose pretty much any typeface that you want, and be guaranteed that it will work for all of your visitors.

This may not directly answer your question, but it does clarify the fact that a user's installed fonts aren't as important anymore, and there's no reason to fall back to plain old Arial.

Comment: Yes but that would be another download and maybe it's just me but with my eyesight I don't see these newer fonts are much better than standard arial

Comment: Valid point! And I'm somewhat on the same page as you. As a former designer I tend to look for fonts that suit my site's look and feel, but honestly in most cases I just fall back to Arial anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

No. To begin with, most smartphones do not have Arial.

The other part of the question asks for font recommendations, which is off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why fallbacks are recommended is that indeed, not all computers have widely distributed fonts available. In particular, most Linux distributions do not come with Arial or other Microsoft fonts due to licensing issues, such as Ubuntu. Setting a `sans-serif` fallback is not a bad idea, since if the font is missing, then it may default to a `serif` family font, which may be very different from the intended font.

To answer your question, Arial will not necessarily work on every computer and mobile device, it will work on most, but it is still good practice to leave a generic fallback.